# Koa2 ES6 new Promise

Tags: mongoose, es6-promise

I'm very much stuck with one silly thing and need help badly.

```
const getTodos = () => (
   new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    todoModel.find().exec().then((result) => {
     resolve(result);
    }).catch((e) => {
     reject(e);
   });
 })
);

export {
 getTodos,
 ..
}
```

So my query is how can pass parameter here? So let's say I want to get a certain record using it's id (findOne()).

Please help

Comment: you... accept a parameter, and... use it. just like any other function. That you're creating a promise inside is mostly irrelevant.

Comment: I did the following

const getTodo = (options) => (
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    todoModel.find(options).exec().then((result) => {
      resolve(result);
    }).catch((e) => {
      reject(e);
    });
  })
);

Comment: But I'm getting 'unexpected parentheses around single function argument' - eslint airbnb :(

Comment: so remove teh parentheses. `= options =>`

Comment: When I do that I get no-used-var

Comment: My fault, sorry. Fixed it and thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
const getTodos = (id) => (
   new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    todoModel.find({_id:id}).exec().then((result) => {
     resolve(result);
    }).catch((e) => {
     reject(e);
   });
 })
);
```